# Multiple Buttons On One Listener - Crashes with two buttons, works for one

Tags: java, android, math, button, onclicklistener

I have 3 buttons in my application, one on each tab of my tabbed activity and I want each one of them to do the same thing.  However, only one when one of the buttons is clicked does it work.  It crashes with the other two.

```
    public void changeOperation (View view) {
    Button b1, b2, b3;
    b1 = findViewById(R.id.prac_op); // Line 116 (As mentioned in exception)
    b2 = findViewById(R.id.operation);
    b3 = findViewById(R.id.instruc_op);
    switch (operation) {
        case 0:
            operation = 1;
            b1.setText("-");
            b2.setText("-");
            b3.setText("-");
            break;
        case 1:
            operation = 2;
            b1.setText("x");
            b2.setText("x");
            b3.setText("x");
            break;
        case 2:
            operation = 3;
            b1.setText("\u00F7");
            b2.setText("\u00F7");
            b3.setText("\u00F7");
            break;
        default:
        case 3:
            operation = 0;
            b1.setText("+");
            b2.setText("+");
            b3.setText("+");
            break;
    }
    Tab3Practice.reroll();
}
```

And the exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.orion31.mathmachine, PID: 24662
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6254)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24705)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6600)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:772)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6254) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24705) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6600) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:772) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
                  at com.orion31.mathmachine.MathMain.changeOperation(MathMain.java:116)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6254) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24705) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6600) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:772)
```

This function is used as a `OnClickListener` for 3 buttons, but only the button the second tab actually successfully calls this function; the other two crash when clicked on.  I have done some research on having multiple buttons on one `OnClickListener`.  Is it a problem with my code, or a restriction with Android?

**Edit: ** MathMain.java

```
public class MathMain extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;
public static int operation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_math_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabDots);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager, true);
}

public void changeOperation (View view) {
Button b1, b2, b3;
b1 = findViewById(R.id.prac_op); // Line 116 (As mentioned in exception)
b2 = findViewById(R.id.operation);
b3 = findViewById(R.id.instruc_op);
switch (operation) {
    case 0:
        operation = 1;
        b1.setText("-");
        b2.setText("-");
        b3.setText("-");
        break;
    case 1:
        operation = 2;
        b1.setText("x");
        b2.setText("x");
        b3.setText("x");
        break;
    case 2:
        operation = 3;
        b1.setText("\u00F7");
        b2.setText("\u00F7");
        b3.setText("\u00F7");
        break;
    default:
    case 3:
        operation = 0;
        b1.setText("+");
        b2.setText("+");
        b3.setText("+");
        break;
}
Tab3Practice.reroll();
}
        public void checkAnswer (View view) {
        TextView num1input = findViewById(R.id.num1);
        TextView num2input = findViewById(R.id.num2);
         TextView num3guess = findViewById(R.id.guessAnswer);

    if (
            (num1input.getText() == null || num1input.getText().equals("")) ||
            (num2input.getText() == null || num2input.getText().equals("")) ||
            (num3guess.getText() == null || num3guess.getText().equals(""))) return;

    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(num1input.getText().toString());
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(num2input.getText().toString());
    double num3 = Double.parseDouble(num3guess.getText().toString());

    CheckDialog cd = new CheckDialog();

    double answer;
    switch (operation) {
        default:
        case 0:
            answer = num1 + num2;
            break;
        case 1:
            answer = num1 - num2;
            break;
        case 2:
            answer = num1 * num2;
            break;
        case 3:
            answer = num1 / num2;
            break;
    }

    if (answer == num3) {
        cd.setMessage("Good Job!  That's Correct.");
    } else if (Math.abs(answer - num3) <= 10) {
        cd.setMessage("Very close!  Keep trying!");
    } else {
        cd.setMessage("Nope!  That's not it.  Try again.");
    }

    num1input.setText("");
    num2input.setText("");
    num3guess.setText("");

    FragmentManager ft = getSupportFragmentManager();
    cd.show(ft, "check_dialog");


}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_math_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_about) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutScreen.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */


public static class CheckDialog extends DialogFragment {

    String message;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Check Your Work").setMessage(message)
                 .setNegativeButton("CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                return new Tab1Check();
            case 1:
                return new Tab2Main();
            case 2:
                return new Tab3Practice();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like you're directly instantiating an `Activity`. What does `MathMain` extend, and how exactly are you creating it?

Comment: @MikeM. MathMain is the main activity it extends `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: could you put your layout xml ?

Comment: @MikeM. https://pastebin.com/C1eMPSdv

Comment: @diegoveloper Tab 1: https://pastebin.com/3YrWNEhP Tab 2: https://pastebin.com/PBr02Hh1 Tab 3: https://pastebin.com/c9aEvdCW

Comment: put the activity_math_main layout

Comment: Please stop with the external links. If you are going to add code please do it by editing your question.

Comment: @diegoveloper https://pastebin.com/per5z9xq

Comment: @Juan My OP is already very long and mostly code, and I cannot fit an entire layout file into a comment

Comment: where is this method : changeOperation ? in which class?

Comment: @diegoveloper MathMain.java.  It is in the post

Comment: First, I said edit your question, not add in comments. Second if you need to post so much code is that you haven't narrowed the problem correctly.

Comment: @MikeM. `changeOperation()` is in the `onClick` property in the layout xml files

Comment: @Juan I am just giving code that is requested

Comment: so you have 3 fragments, each fragment has this method : changeOperation ?

Comment: @diegoveloper changeOperation is only defined once in MathMain.java.  It is the method in the original post.  Multiple Buttons are referencing this function.

Comment: then it's incorrect because your activity does not have those buttons , each button is inside each fragment

Comment: @diegoveloper I actually tried having this function in each Fragment, however it's looking for changeOperation() in MathMain.java.

Comment: don't use onclick method in your layout xml if your button is in your fragment, you have to register the  onClickListener manually inside each fragment

Comment: put the class: MathMain

Comment: @diegoveloper edited op

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each fragment reference your button in onCreateView

```
    public class YourFragment extends Fragment ...

    Button button1;


    public void onCreateView(.... )
      {
          View view = inflate ...
          button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.prac_opl);
      }
```

Add this method in each of your fragments

```
    public void updateText(String text){
        button1.setText(text);
    }
```

Modify your Activity

```
    public class MathMain extends AppCompatActivity { 

    Tab1Check fragmentTab1;
    Tab2Main fragmentTab2;
    Tab3Practice fragmentTab3;

    /** 
    * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide 
    * fragments for each of the sections. We use a 
    * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every 
    * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it 
    * may be best to switch to a 
    * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}. 
    */ 
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter; 

    /** 
    * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents. 
    */ 
    private ViewPager mViewPager; 
    public static int operation; 

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_math_main); 

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar); 
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three 
    // primary sections of the activity. 
    fragmentTab1 = new Tab1Check();
    fragmentTab3 = new Tab2Main();
    fragmentTab3 = new Tab3Practice();
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); 

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter. 
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container); 
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter); 
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1); 

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabDots); 
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager, true); 
    } 


    public void checkAnswer(View view) { 
    TextView num1input = findViewById(R.id.num1); 
    TextView num2input = findViewById(R.id.num2); 
    TextView num3guess = findViewById(R.id.guessAnswer); 

    if ( 
    (num1input.getText() == null || num1input.getText().equals("")) || 
    (num2input.getText() == null || num2input.getText().equals("")) || 
    (num3guess.getText() == null || num3guess.getText().equals(""))) return; 

    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(num1input.getText().toString()); 
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(num2input.getText().toString()); 
    double num3 = Double.parseDouble(num3guess.getText().toString()); 

    CheckDialog cd = new CheckDialog(); 

    double answer; 
    switch (operation) { 
    default: 
    case 0: 
    answer = num1 + num2; 
    break; 
    case 1: 
    answer = num1 - num2; 
    break; 
    case 2: 
    answer = num1 * num2; 
    break; 
    case 3: 
    answer = num1 / num2; 
    break; 
    } 

    if (answer == num3) { 
    cd.setMessage("Good Job! That's Correct."); 
    } else if (Math.abs(answer - num3) <= 10) { 
    cd.setMessage("Very close! Keep trying!"); 
    } else { 
    cd.setMessage("Nope! That's not it. Try again."); 
    } 

    num1input.setText(""); 
    num2input.setText(""); 
    num3guess.setText(""); 

    FragmentManager ft = getSupportFragmentManager(); 
    cd.show(ft, "check_dialog"); 


    } 


    public void changeOperation(View view) { 

    switch(MathMain.operation) 

    { 
    case 0: 
    MathMain.operation = 1; 
    fragmentTab1.updateText("-");
    fragmentTab2.updateText("-");
    fragmentTab3.updateText("-");
    break; 
    case 1: 
    MathMain.operation = 2; 
    fragmentTab1.updateText("x");
    fragmentTab2.updateText("x");
    fragmentTab3.updateText("x");
    break; 
    case 2: 
    MathMain.operation = 3; 
    fragmentTab1.updateText("\u00F7");
    fragmentTab2.updateText("\u00F7");
    fragmentTab3.updateText("\u00F7");
    break; 
    default: 
    case 3: 
    MathMain.operation = 0; 
    fragmentTab1.updateText("+");
    fragmentTab2.updateText("+");
    fragmentTab3.updateText("+"); 
    break; 
    } 

    reroll(); 
    } 
    @Override 
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. 
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_math_main, menu); 
    return true; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_about) { 
    startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutScreen.class)); 
    return true; 
    } 
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
    } 

    /** 
    * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to 
    * one of the sections/tabs/pages. 
    */ 


    public static class CheckDialog extends DialogFragment { 

    String message; 

    @Override 
    public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Check Your Work").setMessage(message) 
    .setNegativeButton("CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
    dialog.cancel(); 
    } 
    }).show(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onStart() { 
    super.onStart(); 
    ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.RED); 
    } 

    public void setMessage(String message) { 
    this.message = message; 
    } 
    } 

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter { 

    SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) { 
    super(fm); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public Fragment getItem(int position) { 
    switch(position) { 
    case 0: 
    return fragmentTab1; 
    case 1: 
    return fragmentTab2; 
    case 2: 
    return fragmentTab3; 
    default: 
    return null; 
    } 
    } 

    @Override 
    public int getCount() { 
    // Show 3 total pages. 
    return 3; 
    } 
    } 
    }
```